# JSF in jetty-equinox, Cannot find Bean classes in other bundles

Tags: jsf, jetty, equinox

I have problems running JSF in an OSGi environment. I am using jetty web container and equinox to provide the OSGi functionality. The structure of my application is as follows:
The first bundle has all the JSF libs, `web.xml` and a `config.xml`. It looks as the following:

```
bundle1
----src/main/java
-------de/package
----------Activator.java
----------JSFResolver.java
----src/main/resource
------ WebContent
----------META-INF
-------------face-config.xml
-------------web.xhtml
----------start.xhtml
-----------include.xhtml
----libs (containing all JSF required Jars)
```

The structure of the second bundle is as follows:

```
bundle2
---src/main/java
------de/package
----------Bean.java
---src/main/resource
------META-INF
---------face-config.xml
------WebContent
---------index.xhtml
```

When running the application of equinox, the bundle1 is the main bundle where all the browser requests are sent to. In the second bundle, the `index.xhtml` file can be retrieved the by first bundle upon request. The `index.xhtml` in bundle 2 gets its values and properties from the 'Bean.java' in bundle 2. The problem comes when i request the 'index.xhtml', the Bean.java class is not found. I think this is because the class loader of bundle1 cannot find it, it has no knowledge of it. So i would like to ask if anyone knows how to solve this problem. If so please do assist me, i have tried all the possibilities i had..

Is it in fact possible to have JSF run on multiple bundles using the same `FaceletsContex`? Can i be able to have seperate faces-config.xml files in each bundle, which can all be connected other faces-config.xml in other bundles? Can anyone please provide me a solution. Sample code would help.

Answer (score 0):

If any one is interested in the answer, in this case, the faces-config.xml is of no use. So i had to use the plug-in.xml file to register all my beans across all plug-in projects. I created an extension point in the main plug-in, which other plug-ins could register their Beans as extension. I had to override the managedBean class of JSF for it to be able to read the bean properties from extension point rather than from the faces-config.xml.
So during runtime, the application reads all extensions registered in the managedBeans extension point, and then creates all the required bean instances from all plug-ins. Therefore the error will no longer be there. If anyone wants to implement JSF in such a structure, you should know that almost all the functionality in the faces-config.xml will have to be moved to the plug-in.xml of the plug-ins, this includes the navigation rules aswell. One has to do alot of customizations but at the end, you get a nice modular JSF application running on equinox, without having to embed it in a .WAR file.. which seems to be very advantageoous.